# Detecting URL Regex with 2 different formats

Tags: javascript, regex, electron

I am parsing a message for URL's, but these URL's come in 2 different formats. Either: `[http://www.google.co.uk Google]` or just the plain `http://www.google.co.uk`.

I am initially matching on URL, then trying to see if the the link is contained in the square brackets, then outputting depending on this, but the application crashes with no error's. Please see what I've tried below. I am unable to see where I am going wrong.

```
var pattern = /(http.*?)/g;

var match = pattern.exec(message);

while (match) {
    var osu_pattern = /\[(http.*?) (.*?\]?)\]/g;
    var osu_match = osu_pattern.exec(message)
    if (osu_match)
    {
        message = message.replace(osu_match[0], `<a href='#' title='${osu_match[1]}' class='link link-external' data-link='${osu_match[1]}'>${osu_match[2]}</a>`);
        osu_match = pattern.exec(message);
    }
    else
    {
        message = message.replace(match[0], `<a href='#' title='${match[0]}' class='link link-external' data-link='${match[0]}'>${match[0]}</a>`);
        match = pattern.exec(message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by grabbing links with a different regex then splitting it out.

```
var pattern = /(\[?(https?:\/\/[^\]\s]+) (.*)\]|(https?:\/\/[^\]\s]+))/g;
while((match = pattern.exec(message)) !== null) {
    if(match[0].startsWith("[") && match[0].endsWith("]"))
    {
        var temp  = match[0].substring(1,match[0].length-1)
        var parts = temp.split(" ");
        var tail  = parts.slice(1).join(" ");
        var result = parts.slice(0,1);
        result.push(tail);
        var lurl = result[0];
        var ltext = result[1];
        message = message.replace(match[0], `<a href='#' title='${ltext}' class='link link-external' data-link='${lurl}'>${ltext}</a>`);
        match = pattern.exec(message);
    }
    else
    {
        if(match[0].startsWith("http"))
        {
            message = message.replace(match[0], `<a href='#' title='${match[0]}' class='link link-external' data-link='${match[0]}'>${match[0]}</a>`);
            match = pattern.exec(message);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For both variants your pattern can be

```
var osu_pattern = /\[(http[^[ ]+?)(?: [^[]+?)\]/g;
var normal_pattern = /(http[^,"' ]+?)[,"' ]/g;
```

[,"' ] - here you can add all symbols, that can end your URL

For your crash, this is probably **infinite loop** in your code.